# fgets function C

Tags: c, fgets

First of all I'd like to tell that I haven't "looked inside" of the sgets() function.
Here is code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma warning(disable:4996)

int main(){
    FILE* file;
    int count = 1;
    char buf[256];
    if (file = fopen("file.txt", "r"))
        while (!feof(file))
        {
            fgets(buf, 256, file);
            printf("%d string: %s", count, buf);
            ++count;
        }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

this is what I wrote in the file.txt:

```
I
was
born
here
.
```

And the output in cmd is:

```
1 string: I
2 string: was
3 string: born
4 string: here
5 string: .
6 string: .
```

How can I refuse doubling of 5th string?

Comment: By `sgets`, do you mean `fgets`?  There's no `sgets` in your code.

Comment: [“while( !feof( file ) )” is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Comment: Don't use `feof`. It is true only when you attempt to read past EOF. So your `while` goes around 6 times.

Comment: @lurker: Specifically, it's only true *after* you've attempted to read past end-of-file.

Comment: @lurker so how can I change while() condition?

Comment: @KeithThompson yeah that's what I meant to say... Wade, see Gopi's answer.

Comment: thanks to all of yours guys.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the below changes to see your code work as expected

```
    while (fgets(buf, 256, file) != NULL)
    {        
        printf("%d string: %s", count, buf);
        ++count;
    }
```

As already mentioned don't use `feof()` as done in your code.